# Is a subset of the kernel of a ring homomorphism always the entire kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In ring theory, is an ideal that is a subset of the kernel of a homomorphism always equal to the entire kernel?
I.e. is it possible for there to be an ideal that maps all its elements to 0, but does not contain all elements of the kernel?

Comment: No, for example if you consider any ring map $\phi:R\rightarrow S$, then $(0)\subset \ker \phi$, but in general $\ker\phi =(0)$ if and only if $\phi$ is injective, but as there are non-injective homomorphisms you can have proper subsets of the kernel which are ideals.

Comment: Perhaps it might help to clarify, if you have an ideal $I$, there is a natural ring map $R\rightarrow R/I$ given by modding out by $I$, and in this case the kernel of this ring map will be always be $I$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The ideal $I=4\mathbb{Z}$ is contained in the ideal $J=2\mathbb{Z}$. The ideal $J$ is the kernel of the quotient homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but its subset $I$ is not equal to it as $2\in 2\mathbb{Z}\setminus 4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question does not seem to match what you are really asking. If you mean to ask:

> "when is it the case that the only ideal $I$ lying in the kernel of a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R \to S$ is the kernel $\ker(\phi)$ itself"

Then since $\{0\}$ is always an ideal,  unless you ask for $I$ to be non-zero, the answer is if and only if $\ker(\phi)=\{0\}$, that is, when $\phi$ is injective.

If you mean to ask

> "when is it the case that the only nonzero ideal $I$ lying in the kernel of a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R \to S$ is the kernel itself",

then the answer is a bit more complicated: since $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal, the condition that there is no nonzero ideal $I$ with $I \subsetneq \ker(\phi)$ is the requirement that $I$ is a *minimal* nonzero ideal. Such ideals, for example, do not exist in the ring $\mathbb Z$, since any nonzero ideal is of the form $d\mathbb Z$ where $d>0$ and $d\mathbb Z \supsetneq 2d\mathbb Z$.

On the other hand, there are rings which contain such ideals: if $R= \mathbb C[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$ then the ideal $\langle x^{n-1}\rangle$ is a minimal non-zero ideal.